# Error occurred during a cryptographic operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, googlebot

A few months ago I rewrote a website from ASP.NET 2.0 to 4.5, it is a webforms project, but I am not using much webforms technology e.g. there is no form-tag with runat server.

My big issue is that my log gets filled with cryptographic errors on ScriptResource.axd and WebResource.axd and I just cannot see why. In my web.config I have set a machineKey with no luck but the "fun" part is that I cannot see a single page where ScriptResource.axd and/or WebResource.axd is used or generated.

As far as I can see it is googlebots that causes the errors so luckily no real users are affected but it is frustrating looking at all these errors in the log. Anything I can do?

Error details

Event code: 3012
Event message: An error occurred processing a web or script resource request. The resource identifier failed to decrypt.
Event time: 3/14/2014 9:43:08 AM
Event time (UTC): 3/14/2014 8:43:08 AM
Event ID: f5d3b02c434c4ff692f713ea64321efc Event sequence: 102 Event occurrence: 4 Event detail code: 0

Exception information:
    Exception type: System.Web.HttpException
    Exception message: This is an invalid script resource request.

Inner exception information (level 1):
    Exception type: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
    Exception message: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.

Answer (score 2):

The errors will eventually go away once the spiders realize that the old links are 404ing now.  It'll probably take a while to flush their indexes.  No action is required on your part.

Comment: All links are exactly the same as before - so the bots must somehow read and execute some cached content?